# Retrieving XML response in AJAX

Tags: xml, ajax, response

I’ve written a java code (Spring controller) snippet to send XML response to an AJAX. Unfortunately I’m unable to get the response as XML using `xhr.responseXML` but can as a text using `xhr.responseText`. Instead of parsing the text at client side would someone suggest what was the actual issue? Here I am enclosing controller and AJAX code.

```
Spring controller code:
-------------------------------
String xmlResp = "<cities>";
xmlResp+="<city>";
xmlResp+="<name>" + "Hyderabad" + "</name>";
xmlResp+="<population>" + "3000000" + "</population>";
xmlResp+="</city>";
xmlResp+="<city>";
xmlResp+="<name>" + "Bangalore" + "</name>";
xmlResp+="<population>" + "4500000" + "</population>";
xmlResp+="</city>";
xmlResp+="</cities>";

response.setContentType("text/xml");
response.getWriter().write(xmlResp);


AJAX code:
-----------------------------

reading as XML:

var xml=xhr.responseXML;
        alert(xml);

reading as Text
var text=xhr.responseText;
        alert(text);
```

for convenience the XML structure:

```
<cities>
    <city>
        <name>Hyderabad</name>
        <population>3000000</population>
    </city>
    <city>
        <name>Bangalore</name>
        <population>4500000</population>
    </city>
</cities>
```

Comment: ppl, identified sol using FireBug. thx to all

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is not well-formed:

```
String xmlResp = "'<'cities>";
```

will give:

```
'<'cities>
```

- **Do** use a validator or lint to check your XML
- **Don't** build an XML document by mashing strings together, use an XML library instead

Comment: it's a typo mistake. Pl. consider it as String xmlResp = "<cities>";

Comment: If you are going to provide a reduced test case, then test it actually demonstrates the problem. It would also be a good idea to show the generated XML and not just the Java that produces it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Below is the XML content:

<cities>
 <city>
  <name>Hyderabad</name>
  <population>3000000</population>
 </city>
 <city>
  <name>Bangalore</name>
  <population>4500000</population>
 </city>
</cities>